# inserting array using button php

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys i've been trying to insert an bunch of data from array and variable into database using button , but it can't be inserted and the database still empty , is there anyone who know where is my mistake ?

here is my code

```
 <?php 
include 'koneksi.php';
$arr_nf = array(1,0.334,-0.334,-1);
$arr_ef = array(0,0.333,0.667,1);
$arr_lf = array(1,0.667,0.333,0);
$kelas = "80 keatas" ;
$iduser = "8" ;

$query = mysql_query(" select id_alternatif from tb_alternatif where kelas   = '".$kelas."' order by nama "); // run query
$idalter = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

  $idalter[] = $row; 
}


////////////////////////////////////////// RANGKING LF
foreach ($arr_lf as $val){ // net flow kali 1000
$arr_lfx[]= $val * 1000 ;
}
$int_lfx = array_map( // rubah jd integer
    function($value) { return (int)$value; },
    $arr_lfx );
    $lfx_copy = $int_lfx;
    rsort($lfx_copy);
    $lfx_copy = array_flip($lfx_copy);

    foreach($int_lfx as $val){
    $rangkinglf[] = ($lfx_copy[$val]+1);
    }
 ////////////////////////////////////////// 
 $jumlah_atlet = count($arr_nf);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

       for($x=0; $x<$jumlah_atlet ;$x++){


            mysql_query(" INSERT INTO tb_histori(id_histori, id_user, id_alternatif, kelas, nilai, rangking, waktu) values(NULL, '$iduser', '".$idalter[$x]['id_alternatif']."', '$kelas', '$arr_nf[$x]', '$rangkingnf[$x]', now());") or die(mysql_error()); };

};
print_r($jumlah_atlet);
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title> insert data array using only button </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="submit" type="button" value="Print & Save" onClick="" />
        </form>
 </body>

 <?php 

        $data = mysql_query("select * from tb_histori");
        $no = 1;
        while($d = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $d['id_user']; ?></td>   
            <td><?php echo $d['id_alternatif']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $d['kelas']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $d['nilai']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $d['rangking']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $d['waktu']; ?></td>


        </tr>

        <br>


        <?php } ?>



        <br>
        </html>
```

Comment: where did you get this code from? and what errors are you getting? running off local or hosted site? If you don't know what your code does, then it isn't our job to test/debug it.

Comment: that's hurting my brain trying to figure out what is happening with that code

Comment: `onClick=""` that does nothing and probably why your button's not firing everything inside that conditional statement as is the wrong type `type="button"`. There, I have ***debugged*** this ***for you***. The ball is now in your court, *as it were*.

Comment: @RamRaider : sorry :(

Comment: @AryaPutra  
Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This looks like something I would see in a php shell script jfc.